# Objective-C - Handle Large Amount of Object Allocations

Tags: objective-c, json, performance, memory

Assuming I don't control what the server sent to me, and I received a big chunk of JSON which I have to create thousands of objects out of before I can use it inside my UITableView/UICollectionView. How would I improve the performance of my application?

Example of my objects which mapped to the JSON response:

```
@interface Address : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Person *person;
...
@end

@interface Person : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CreditCard *card;
...
@end

@interface CreditCard : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Bank *bank;
...
@end
```

The JSON data that comes back to me will have thousands of addresses, each address can have multiple persons, each person can have multiple credit cards, so on and so forth...Once again, I don't control the JSON datasource that provided to me by the server so I cannot implement data chunking mechanism.

**Clarification**: There is a bottleneck/performance issues in object allocations and not UITableView/UICollectionView related problem.

Comment: Is there actually a performance problem in your app or is this a hypothetical? Is the bottleneck in the allocation of memory for your objects or is it in the tableview?

Comment: Why not create only those objects which are needed by UITableView/UICollectionView at a specific time to display on the screen ?

Comment: @CrimsonChris it is an actual performance problem. It is not tableview related as the bottleneck is at objects allocation.

Comment: @NofelMahmood That means I have to store that big junk of JSON somewhere and I would have to open it, traverse the tree, find appropriate elements, and create the objects. I don't think it would improve the performance.

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to implement some sort of client side batching of the data. I think what @NofelMahmood meant was to defer the creation of objects to just before you actually need to show them.

Comment: you should clarify what *specific* allocations are taking place. some code would be handy too. are there times when you can share a single buffer between multiple objects? `NSData` and `NSString` both have initializers that dont copy if you can use them.

Comment: I think you'll need to narrow the scope of this question to get an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dont specify enough to know for sure if this is a helpful answer, but if you have a large `NSString` from the server, and then are creating a copy as `NSData` such as with `dataUsingEncoding:` to send to `NSJSONSerialization` then that is going to be a lot of unnecessary copying.

the same is true if you have `NSData` (or even raw bytes) you are converting to `NSString`.

Ideally you would have a buffer of raw bytes returned from the server that you construct an `NSData` instance from using `dataWithBytesNoCopy:length:` or `dataWithBytesNoCopy:length:freeWhenDone:`. then you pass this instance to `NSJSONSerialization`.

After that I'm not sure what to tell you without seeing some code.

Comment: Absolutely true: For lowest memory usage, make sure you receive the JSON as NSData. Do _not_ convert it to an NSString.

Answer (score 1):

Are we allowed just to say: don't create thousands of objects before you use them inside your tableview?

Instead of e.g.

```
for(NSDictionary *JSONObject in allJSONObjects)
{
    [array addObject:[MyLocalObject objectWithJSONObject:JSONObject]];
}

dispatch_blah_blah_blah( { [tableViewDataSource haveSomeObjects:array]; } )

...

- (void)haveSomeObjects:(NSArray *)array 
{
    _tableObjects = array;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Go with:

```
for(NSDictionary *JSONObject in allJSONObjects)
{
    [array addObject:[MyLocalObject objectWithJSONObject:JSONObject]];

    if([array count] == 100)
    {
        dispatch_blah_blah_blah( { [tableViewDataSource addSomeObjects:array]; } )
        [array removeAllObjects];
    }
}

if([array count])
    dispatch_blah_blah_blah( { [tableViewDataSource addSomeObjects:array]; } )

...

- (void)addSomeObjects:(NSArray *)array
{
    NSUInteger oldIndex = [_tableObjects count];
    [_tableObjects addObjectsFromArray:array];

    NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(NSUInteger index = oldIndex; index < [_tableObjects count]; index++)
        [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathWithRow:(NSInteger)index column:0]]; 

    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:<whatever>];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

NSJSONSerialization will create all the strings, and NSNumbers, and everything for you. Unless you set options to create mutable objects, all these NSString objects are immutable (NSNumber is immutable anyway). Once you have an immutable object, making a copy doesn't actually allocate more memory.

So for example the Person object needs some memory for the object itself, but no additional memory for the name stored inside it; that is already created by NSJSONSerialization.

Answer (score 0):

NSJSONSerialization will create all the strings, and NSNumbers, and everything for you. Unless you set options to create mutable objects, all these NSString objects are immutable (NSNumber is immutable anyway). Once you have an immutable object, making a copy doesn't actually allocate more memory.

So for example the Person object needs some memory for the object itself, but no additional memory for the name stored inside it; that is already created by NSJSONSerialization.

You might consider converting JSON data to your objects only when it is needed, if it is more of a performance issue than a memory issue.

Comment: it looks like you mistakenly answered twice. you should merge your answers.